# Generate Box.com Access Token Using Guzzle

Tags: php, http, guzzle, box

I'm struggling with generating access token using the authorization code for Box.com API. I've tried  lot's of ways using the Guzzle to make a post request to Box.com OAuth/token API to generate access token using the authorization code. However, I've not got any success yet.

Here's the following code now I am trying.

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;

$client = new Client();

$request = $client->post('http://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token', [], [
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'client_id' => 'mobvhx1foqtclyccza4hdvst11lkdcjb',
    'client_secret' => 'fRpwlcRxM5rumDL2WnjA0F69QaiRZxct',
    'code' => 'CSSBd0tJnYLRTowxg0tS4h2mA7Vow0WS'
]);

$response = $request->send();
```

And here's the error I'm getting :(

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException' with message 'Client error response [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request [url] http://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token' in vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Exception/BadResponseException.php:43 Stack trace: #0 vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php(145): Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException::factory(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response)) #1 [internal function]: Guzzle\Http\Message\Request::onRequestError(Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)) #2 vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(158): call_user_func(Array, Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)) #3 vendor/symfony/event in vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Exception/BadResponseException.php on line 43
```

Can anyone please help what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just figured it out myself by making all the parameters URL encoded and the request sent over to HTTPS. Here's the correct code which someone may find helpful.

```
$request = $client->post('https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token', [], [
    'grant_type' => urlencode('authorization_code'),
    'client_id' => urlencode('mobvhx1foqtclyccza4hdvst11lkdcjb'),
    'client_secret' => urlencode('fRpwlcRxM5rumDL2WnjA0F69QaiRZxct'),
    'code' => urlencode('CSSBd0tJnYLRTowxg0tS4h2mA7Vow0WS')
]);
```